# Phase is not linear for the time domain signal of a Gaussian spectrum

Tags: matlab, fft, gaussian, delta

As far as I understand from mathematics, the Inverse Fourier Transform (IFFT) of a Gaussian is a Gaussian. If I have a Gaussian with a mean (mu) and variance (sigma^2), I can write it as,

```
S(f) = 1/sqrt(2 * pi * sigma^2) .* exp(-(f - mu).^2/(2 * sigma^2))
```

Where f is the frequency axis. From Matematica, I found that the analytical expression for IFFT of the square root of the Gaussian pulse as,

```
s(t) = (2 / pi)^(1/4) .* sqrt(sigma) .* exp(-t .* 2 .* pi .* ((sigma)^2 .* 2 .* pi .* t + 1j .* mu)))
```

I used `2 * pi * t` instead of `t` from Mathematica because they use angular terms. I don't use this expression in MATLAB anyway. I use IFFT to compare with this expression.

If we closely examine this time-domain `s(t)`, we notice that the phase is linear. I define the frequency axis the following way,

```
f = linspace(-1/(2 * PRT), 1/(2 * PRT), N);
```

Therefore, after doing an IFFT, if I divide `2 * pi * mu` from the phase of the signal, I should see a linearly varying thing from `0` to `(N - 1)*PRT`.

I have `N = 60000` and `PRT = 1e-3` so, I should see a plot from `0` till `60` seconds linearly. However, I see a nonlinear plot that ends before `60` seconds.

If I do the same exercise with a Dirac delta instead of a Gaussian spectrum, I see the linear phase correctly.

Picture for Gaussian:

[image]

Code for Gaussian:

```
clear; 
% close all;


lambda = 0.03;


mu = 4 * 2 / lambda; % Mean Doppler
sigma = 0.2 * 2 / lambda;


PRT = 1e-3; 
f_amb = 1/(2 * PRT);


N = 60000; % Total number of points in time axis


f = linspace(-f_amb, f_amb, N); % velocity axis for the entire rotation



S_ = gaussmf(f, [sigma, mu]);


s_num = ifft(ifftshift(sqrt(S_)));


figure; plot(unwrap(angle(s_num))/(2*pi*mu));
```

Picture for Dirac Spectrum:

[image]

Code for Dirac spectrum: You can add this one just below the above code for Gaussian:

```
[~, idx1] = (min(abs(f - mu)));
S_Dirac_f = dirac(f - f(idx1)); 
idx = S_Dirac_f == Inf;
S_Dirac_f(idx) = 1;

s_num_dirac = ifft(ifftshift(sqrt(S_Dirac_f)));

figure; plot(unwrap(angle(s_num_dirac))/(2*pi*mu));
```

Comment: When `f = linspace(-1/(2 * PRT), 1/(2 * PRT), N);`, and `N` is even, you don't sample the origin. This means that you have an additional shift. With `N=6000` this is very small, but it's still there. You also have `ifft(ifftshift(sqrt(S_)))`, why the `sqrt`? It is bound to change the phase of your signal.

Comment: Yes, of course, I don't sample the origin and I should use an odd number of points here. However, that is not the problem. I have investigated enough with odd and even. I use square root because the Gaussian one is my power spectrum. And, I don't think it should change the linearity of the phase because a square root over phase is just multiplication of 1/2 in the exponent.